# Handling .CSVs in various folders differently with Powershell and export to .html

Tags: html, powershell

I have a bunch of .csv files that are stored in different folders that I want to put out as clickable buttons in a .html file (separated by folder name).

In my code I added the department `IT` and it works that way but it's not elegant to handle every department we have like that.

I feel totally lost and spent hours without any progress. I have the following code:

```
$out = 'C:\Project\test.html'
$it = "C:\Project\IT\"
$head = @"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
"@
$Head | Out-File -filepath $out -Encoding utf8

#IT
$ITText = @"
<h3>IT</h3>
"@ 
$ITText | Out-File -FilePath $out -Encoding utf8 -Append
Get-ChildItem $it -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.BaseName
    $id = '{0}_{1}' -f $name, (Get-Date).Ticks  # to make this id unique, append the Ticks to the name    
    $Pre = @"
<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-Warning btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#$id">$name</button>
<div id="$id" class="collapse">
"@
    $Post = '</p></div>'
    Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent $pre -PostContent $post | 
    Out-File -FilePath $out -Encoding utf8 -Append
}
```

This is a Follow up to [a prev question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871747/powershell-script-to-convert-csv-to-html-and-handling-multiple-files)

Thanks!

Comment: You can try `Get-ChildItem` in C:\Project\ and then split that part and then extract folder name (same as department name) and place it in file.

Comment: I tried these both:
1. `$in=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Project\ | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select-object fullname`
2. `$in=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Project\ | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select-object -expand name`
and then use these one instead of $it but the scripts spits out errors with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to recurse the `$in` path and group the CSV files by their subfolder name, which apparently is the Department name you want to output as `<h3>` tag.

```
$in  = 'C:\Project'
$out = 'C:\Project\test.html'

$head = @'
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
'@
$Head | Out-File -filepath $out -Encoding utf8

$Pre = @'
<div class="container">
<h2></h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{0}">{1}</button>
<div id="{0}" class="collapse">
'@
$Post = '</p></div>'

Get-ChildItem $in -Filter *.csv -File -Recurse | 
    Group-Object {Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf} |   # group the files by the folder name and loop through
    ForEach-Object {
        # $_.Name is the name of the Group, aka the folder name aka the department name
        "<h3>$($_.Name)</h3>" | Out-File -FilePath $out -Encoding utf8 -Append
        # inside each department folder loop through the files
        foreach($file in $_.Group) {
            $name = $file.BaseName
            $id = '{0}_{1}' -f $name, (Get-Date).Ticks  # to make this id unique, append the Ticks to the name
            # use the $Pre template to fill in the placeholders
            $precontent = $Pre -f $id, $name
            Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent $precontent -PostContent $post | 
            Out-File -FilePath $out -Encoding utf8 -Append
        }
    }
# write html closing tags
'</body.</html>' | Out-File -FilePath $out -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

<sup>P.S. You forgot the opening `<html` and `<head>` tags. Also don't forget to close off the html by writing closing tags `</body></html>`</sup>

Comment: Thanks again, is exactly what i wanted!